# How to get changes of transient attributes in models tracked by ActiveRecords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Assuming a model with a non transient attribute **a** and a transient attribute **b**:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :b
end
```

I want to get Rails to track attribute changes of both attributes. Currently, **model.changes** does only track changes of attribute a.

What I have tried so far:

Use **ActiveModel::Dirty** methods:

```
include ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :b

  define_attribute_methods [:b]

  def b
     @b
  end

  def b=(val)
     b_will_change! unless val == @b
     @b = val
  end
end
```

Unfortunately Rails doesn't like it and throws a TypeError.

Are there any ideas how to get this done?

Comment: This attribute is not persisted in the database. So what is an initial value you want to track changes of?

Comment: Sure, the initial value of a transient attribute is nil, but a change always happened when the current value of that transient attribute gets overwritten. Same as for persisted attributes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a non-persisted variable is either nil or dirty.